# Swift iOS: Silent push, triggers app to make sound and vibration?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to make an app where you could send a warning to other users which then will trigger an alarm on the receivers phone.

So my plan is to send a silent warning to the receiver, which then triggers sounds and vibrations on the receivers phone from the app.

So basically my question is, is it possible to open an app on a phone through a silent push?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself??

Comment: I have done a lot of research but cant really seem to get a hang of it. Im quite new to swift, but I see that apple has a lot of restrictions for those kind of things.

Comment: and why android tag??

Comment: Because I am going to do the same in android

Answer (score 1):

This is done with push notifications in iOS. See [Apple's description](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).

> Apps must be configured appropriately before they can receive local or remote notifications. The configuration process differs slightly on iOS and OS X, but the basic principles are the same. At launch time, your app registers to receive notifications and works with the system to configure that notification support. Once registration is complete, you can start creating notifications for delivery to your app. Your app then handles these incoming notifications and provides an appropriate response.

But note that it is up to the receiving user to determine how he wants to be alerted.